# One-to-many relationship Semantic MediaWiki properties

Tags: semantic-mediawiki

Is it possible to define a one-to-many relationship between two properties (both lists with allowed values) of a SMW-page?

And if so, how?

Answer (score 0):

A property contains a single value; that's not a limitation as such, it's an [RDF triple essentially with subject, object, and predicate](http://blog.swirrl.com/articles/introduction-to-rdf/).

You define relationships in pages. The way a 1-to-N works in that case is, on one page declare N instances of one property with different values.

This is usually handled in a template definition of that page; as I recall, it's the SemanticForms extension which provides you with an easy to use checkbox to allow this.

[image]